# How can I mail a command output via Sendmail

Tags: linux, cron, sendmail

I want to cron a simple commandline output via the standard linux sendmail function (using Centos).

The command is: `ll -rt | grep error` 
This will give me a list of error log files.

I want the solution as simple as possible, can I do something like `sendmail user@example.com  < ll -rt | grep error`. Or is there a more elegant way?

Btw, this gives me an error output: `bash: ll -rt | grep error: No such file or directory`

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipe:

```
ll -rt | grep error | sendmail user@example.com
```

`<` is for redirection from a file, not a command, so it's trying to read from the file named `ll`.

You obviously already know about pipelines, since you used it to pipe the output of `ls` to `grep`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick- and spot-on answer :)